# Compatible versions for python and chameleon

Tags: python, chameleon

I want to know the proper Chameleon version for python 2.6. Also want to know a table structure like which version actually suits which version of Chameleon.

Answer (score 1):

All Chameleon versions work on Python 2.6. From the [Chameleon documentation](http://chameleon.repoze.org/docs/latest/):

> The language used is page templates, originally a Zope invention, but available here as a standalone library that you can use in any script or application running Python 2.5 and up (including 3.x and pypy).

On python 2.5 and 2.6 there are some dependencies you need:

> There are no required library dependencies on Python 2.7 and up. On 2.5 and 2.6, the ordereddict and unittest2 packages are set as dependencies.

A quick scan of the [changelog](https://github.com/malthe/chameleon/blob/master/CHANGES.rst) shows that this support has been constant throughout the 2.x series of Chameleon, with minor compatibility fixes here and there, with 2.6.2 fixing Python 3.3 support.

Just use the latest version and you should be more than fine.